# Spring MVC UI service behind Zuul (checking csfr)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

I have a ui service is based on spring mvc. The ui service is behind Zuul reverse proxy. The reverse proxy generates a csfr token. How can I get the token in the ui service and insert it to a form and send to a client?

P.S. The ui service is a resource server in oauth2 terminology.

Comment: I face a similar problem, I put the login form on the OAuth2 server and try to redirect from Zuul. Without zuul everything wired nicely but the moment you try to take the next step things are failing.